# TypeScript: Function must return a single prop of object with unknow properties

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, react-typescript

The thing is, im trying to tell TypeScript that a method of a 'column' object called 'selector' recives a 'row' object with unknow properties, this method should return anything as long as belong to the 'row' object.

**I'm using TypeScript v4.5.5**

---

### The problem

So far I tryed this:

```
type ColumnCommonProps = {
  _index: number;
  title: string;
  selector: (row: {[key: string]: any}) => keyof typeof row;
};
```

The thing "works" but TypeScript it's not yelling when I want to, for instance:

```
const someRow = {
    name: 'Jhon'
    surName: 'Doe'
  };

const column: ColumnCommonProps = {
    _index: 0,
    title: 'Last Name',
    //trying to return a prop that does not exist in 'row' object
    selector: (row: {[key: string]: any}) => row.lastName, 
  };

column.selector(someRow)
//TypeScript should trow something like "Property 'lastName' doesn't exist in row"
```

---

### The rest of my code

I don't know if it's even possible to do a typing like this, however heres the whole react component interface

```
type ColumnCommonProps = {
  _index: number;
  title: string;
  selector: (row: {[key: string]: any}) => keyof typeof row;
};

type ColumnTruncateType =
  | {
      sortable?: false;
      sortMethod?: never;
    }
  | {
      sortable: true;
      sortMethod?: () => undefined;
    };

type ColumnType = ColumnCommonProps & ColumnTruncateType;

export interface ISuperTableProps {
  columns: ColumnType[];
  rows: {}[];
  title?: string;
  defaultSortMethod?: () => undefined;
  exportable?: boolean;
  pagination?: boolean;
  searcher?: boolean;
}
```

Comment: You need to let the type `ColumnCommonProps` know about `someRow` somehow, one way is to make the type into `ColumnCommonProps<T extends object> = { ... selector: (row: T) => T[keyof T]; }` and declare your column as `ColumnCommonProps<typeof someRow>`

Comment: I don't think that I can do that. As you can probably infer, the row argument is a data row for a set of colums from a table. This row could be literally anithing, even a JSX element, there is the point, that those who want to use my library can pass an array of object with any kind of data to my table. Mybe i'm messing with the logic itself, but I don't know

Comment: are you saying that your library defines the `column` variable and your users pass their own `someRow` into your `column`'s `selector` function? In this case, it's physically impossible for typescript to know about `someRow` during the transpile time of your library

Comment: Yeah, i knew it. However, I know that someRow will be an object. I can't know wich properties that object will have. I will rethink my logic, thanks for you response

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generic type to define the selector

```js
type ColumnCommonProps<T> = {
  _index: number;
  title: string;
  selector: (row: T) => keyof T
};

type someRowNeeded = {
  name: string;
  surName: string;
  lastName: string
}

const someRow = {
    name: 'Jhon'
    surName: 'Doe'
  };

const column: ColumnCommonProps<someRowNeeded> = {
    _index: 0,
    title: 'Last Name',
    selector: (row: {[key: string]: any}) => row.lastName, 
  };

column.selector(someRow) //Error! 'lastName' is declared here.
```

Here then wherever you interface with the user of the library you have to take the generic shape of the row. Basically you'll have to pass the generic around.

```js
type ColumnCommonProps<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
    _index: number;
    title: string;
    selector: (row: T) => keyof T
  };

type ColumnTruncateType =
  | {
      sortable?: false;
      sortMethod?: never;
    }
  | {
      sortable: true;
      sortMethod?: () => undefined;
    };

type ColumnType<T extends Object> = ColumnCommonProps<T> & ColumnTruncateType;

type ISuperTableProps<T> = {
  columns: ColumnType<T>
  rows: T[]
  title?: string;
  defaultSortMethod?: () => undefined;
  exportable?: boolean;
  pagination?: boolean;
  searcher?: boolean;
}

function createISuperTable<T extends Object>(props: ISuperTableProps<T>) {
  //your implemntation here
}
```

[View on TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwK4FsB28UrmgCgJzjAGcAeAFSggA9gI0ATYqAJQgGM58HTjh8AlmgDmAGigBDNCAB8MqAF4oAbwBQUDVAD6QhjQBcUNKgBGEfAG51m4AOAIIhvoJFXNUYhAftgXQwApCAHdDcgBKRXkAawgQOAAzKHJrAF8rVVBIWERUNHJ8JDR2CTpycGgFawAfFWt3Yi5gCRMHAH5DeIkETzd3D0aAWQhgAAs4BnajCAA3c16NFOravv78JpbHKH4kCHnNBrWh0fHJ-wiFeUK9eKEIBj201Qzy7OR0MsgKKlp6JigAeRMACsOMB5Ep4G8MHAsDgCEQyOR5AAyV65fKFYqlcrpTLQACSAGUkJB8ORmg54SQKODllBOFDiIZIejyjTrMEmUkANoAXWstnsEEmziEwl61wkSAQwEJg2GYwmAXOl0YEBuaDuvRoYEaFOFhhMcEQECkvTAEmEQhKAhwkyNJrN1k8Enw7BG5ntxocTsWqnimNsOHp+FNdCJJPM5I2XxodEYzEBIJ8Mn8YEIJEMEdJ0cpGcRMgiag0AHoS3EkPgoAIUGAHOgmkG0FAPaHVCkgA)

You can also strictly type the object return value and title to be of specific values using string delimiters and string literals, but perhaps that's out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write an answer, i'll check it out and i'll let you know if this works well with my component logic!!